# Under what scenarios a developer should inherit constructors and destructors of a parent class into child class?

Tags: oop

As all private and public attributes and methods are inherited into a child class from its parent class then why would constructors and destructors be inherited into a child class?

Is there a real life scnario?

Comment: In some languages it is not possible to inherit these methods.

Comment: Why is that? And can you name them please? I like to look further into it.

Comment: C# for one. Constructors and destructors belong to the type that declares them - you can't inherit them (you can chain constructors in C#, but not inherit them).

Comment: @Oded How about C++ and Java?

Comment: Not an expert on either of those.

Answer (score 1):

In most programming languages constructors and descructors are **not inherited** automatically. Usually  base class can provide one set of constructors and child class can provide another set of constructors.

I think that *in most cases* abstract derived class should provide the same set of constructor as base class do (i.e. "inherit" constructors from the base class), but concrete derived class can resolve some of base class's constructor arguments and provide more usable set of constructors:

Consider following case. Let suppose we have a base class called BaseWCFProxy that requires string as endpoint name:

```
abstract class BaseWCFProxy 
{
  public BaseWCFProxy(string endpointName)
  {}
}

class ConcreteProxy : BaseWCFProxy
{
  public ConcreteProxy() : base("ConcreteProxyEndPoint") {}
}
```

But you decide to add additional abstract class between BaseProxy and ConcreteProxy than you should provide the same set of constructors as base class:

class DualChannelBaseProxy : BaseWCFProxy 
{
  public DualChannelBaseProxy(string enpointName) : base(endpointName) {}
}

So the rule of thumb is: if you write a abstract child you should consider to "inherit" all base classes constructors. If you write a concrete child you can provide separate set of constructors that would be appropriate for your clients.

P.S. We don't have the same issue with destructors because there is no such notion like destructors overloading. And they're inherited by default: i.e. descendant can provide some additional logic but it definitely should call base version.